# ComboBox bound to a ObservableCollection does not update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ComboBox that uses a ObservableCollection as the source. I have the source bound as follows

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="False"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:CollectionControl.Settings}, Path=SamplingPeriodIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionChanged="onPeriodControlSelectionChanged"
          Name="PeriodControl"
          ItemsSource="{StaticResource test}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SamplingPeriod}" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TrackVis}, ConverterParameter=GroupIndex}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

TrackVis is a converter that determines if the element is visible or collapsed depending on an external property which has INotifyPropertyChanged implemented.

Everything works as expected the first time the ComboBox is displayed, but the ComboBox is never refreshed to reflect changes. I must be missing something, but as of now everything I have tried fails.

Here is the code for the converter

```
public class IsVisibleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var tempObj = (SamplingPeriods) value;
        if (tempObj.GroupIndex >= CollectionControl.Settings.SamplingFrequencyIndex)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Also, here is the collection

```
public class PeriodsCollection : ObservableCollection<SamplingPeriods>
{
    public PeriodsCollection()
    {
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("1/16 of a second", 13));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("1/8 of a second", 12));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("1/4 of a second", 11));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("1/2 of a second", 10));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("1 second", 9));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("2 seconds", 8));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("4 seconds", 7));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("8 seconds", 6));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("16 seconds", 5));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("32 seconds", 4));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("64 seconds", 3));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("128 seconds", 2));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("256 seconds", 1));
        Add(new SamplingPeriods("512 seconds", 0));
    }
}

public class SamplingPeriods
{
    public SamplingPeriods(string samplingPeriod, int groupIndex)
    {
        SamplingPeriod = samplingPeriod;
        GroupIndex = groupIndex;
    }

    public string SamplingPeriod { get; private set; }
    public int GroupIndex { get; private set; }
}
```

The idea is that the selected sampling frequency limits the sampling periods that are available. The sampling frequency index ranges from  0 to 11. For example, if the sampling index is 9 the only valid sampling periods would have a GroupIndex >=
9. The other sampling periods would be collapsed.

Comment: Why StaticResource and not simply name of property ?

Comment: Changes to TrackVis, or the selectedindex, or both?

Comment: It's really important, when asking a question like this, to be specific about what's not updating.  Are new items not appearing in the `ComboBox` when you add them to the collection?  Is the `SelectedIndex` not updating when you change the bound property in code?  What, specifically, is and is not happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to track samplingfrequency index. then you must bind to an object that have such property and implements INotifyPropertyChanged.Or, as I have already said, propagate this event to the object that is your binding source, and raise correct propertychanged on it. Otherwise, binding engine would know nothing of the changes of that property.
Bind to the `CollectionControl.Settings` with a `Path = SamplingFrequencyIndex`

Comment: When I add path = propertyWithChangeNotification, the TrackVis converter is never called.

Comment: By property with a change notification I mean the property that changes in your situation. Did this property resides in the "test" object?

Comment: In VisualStudio go to the view>output. When you debugging your app are there any binding errors in the output?

Comment: 1. the property does not reside in the "test object" 2. No binding errors.

Comment: can you update your example with the code of the converter? Now I do not understand why are you binding to one object, but trying to reflect the property changes of another object. That code will not work

Comment: SamplingFrequencyIndex is the property that raises propertychanged in your scenario? can you bind to a CollectionControl.Settings with a SamplingFrequencyIndex path?

Comment: Yes the SamplingFrequencyIndex raises the propertychanged and can be bound.

Comment: I got this to work but with a lot of code smell. So I changed my approach (see comment under BalamBalam). Thanks for your time and effort. It has helped me get a deeper understanding of WPF.

Answer (score 0):

SamplingPeriods needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and you need to call NotifyPropertyChanged on the set.  I will take it on faith at CollectionControl.Settings.SamplingFrequencyIndex holds the value you expect you from you code it is not clear where you set that.  When you change SamplingFrequencyIndex you need to call NotifyPropertyChanged on ObservabaleCollection of possible force a refresh.   There has got to be a better way to do this.   Change SamplingPeriods and pass a reference to SamplingFrequencyIndex so the actual objects you want to change, change.

```
   CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lbFields.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```

Comment: you got me thinking along with Abe and I decided to go with a different approach. I created a CollectionViewSource and a filter. Then when the SamplingFrequencyIndex event is fired I force a view.refresh for the CollectionViewSource. Works great! Thanks to both for setting me on this path.

Answer (score 0):

If your period and your frequency are both held in the same class, why not expose the list of available periods also? You can then use the CollectionView to filter your collection instead of the converter & visibility:

```
// initialize in your constructor
public PeriodsCollection AvailablePeriods { get; private set; }

public int SamplingFrequencyIndex
{
    get { return samplingFrequencyIndex; }
    set
    {
        samplingFrequencyIndex = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SamplingFrequencyIndex");
        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AvailablePeriods) as ListCollectionView;
        view.Filter = o => ((SamplingPeriod)o).GroupIndex >= value;
    }
}
```